# How to serialize nil to JSON as nil, not an empty place?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In my controller/action I have some values that are nil

```
def my_action
  @var1 = get_boolean_value || nil
  @var2 = get_int_value || nil
  @var3 = get_string_value || nil

  # there many more, any one can happen to be nil
end
```

When I create a JSON object in a view out of them, nil values get rendered as an empty space:

```
:javascript
  window.MyObj = {
    var1: #{@var1},
    var2: #{@var1},
    var2: #{@var3}
  }
```

The issue is that when a value is nil, it's rendered as an empty space, not nil itself.

```
:javascript
  window.MyObj = {
    var1: ,
    var2: 33,
    var2: 
  }
```

How to cure that?

Comment: `empty space` ? there's no such thing in javascript (not in the way you've portrayed it) ... but then the confusing thing is you mention JSON, and there is no JSON in your question

Comment: You're _interpolating_ the values into the result. `#{@var1}` is like a placeholder which is being replaced by the actual value. So if the value is missing, `var1: #{@var1},` becomes `var1: ,` – it doesn't cause the whole line to be removed, let alone stray commas.

Comment: BTW, it's "empty string", not "empty space". The space after `:` is already in your template.

Comment: If your methods return either a non-`nil` value or `nil` then `|| nil` in the assignment is superfluous. And in case of a boolean return value it's even counterproductive because it turns `false` into `nil`.

Answer (score 6):

One should not reinvent the wheel. Use `JSON` ruby standard library to serialize json:

```
require 'json'
json = {var1: nil, var2: 42, var2: nil}.to_json
#⇒ "{\"var1\":null,\"var2\":42,\"var3\":null}"
```

and then:

```
:javascript
  window.MyObj = json
```